# Emit signals or post events from QRunnable

Tags: multithreading, events, qt, threadpool, signals-slots

Is emitting signals inside `QRunnable::run()` a right thing to do? I need to inform my GUI thread that image processed by `QRunnable` is done. I am using `QThreadPool`/`QRunnable` because I need to be able to add new tasks to the pool while there are tasks in it already. I find it kind of hard to do that with `QtConcurrent` and `QFutureWatcher`.

The `QRunnable` is using a `QObject` created in `run()` to connect to the target `QObject` and emit signals.

If emitting from `QRunnable` is not a good thing, is it possible to post events from there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, emitting signals and posting events are fine things to do in a `QRunnable::run()` because they are both thread-safe. For the signals and events to be handled properly, the QObjects must have the correct thread affinity. See [Threads and QObjects](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/threads-qobject.html) for more details.

Comment: I think my confusion is from the impression that signals and events require a thread to have an even loop to work. There's no mention in Qt docs if QThreadPool threads have their own loop. Or is the event loop is only required for receiving?

Comment: Yes, the event loop is only required for QObjects receiving signals from other threads.